# mkdtemp requires _DARWIN_C_SOURCE for unistd.h

Tags: c, linux, macos, posix

I am a little puzzled. I have project that I compile with

```
CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc/main -pthread -rdynamic -DNDEBUG $(OPTFLAGS) -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700
```

Now I want to use `mkdtemp` and therefor include `unistd.h`

```
char *path = mkdtemp(strdup("/tmp/test-XXXXXX"));
```

On MacOSX the compilation gives some warnings

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mkdtemp’
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

but compiles through. While `mkdtemp` does return a non-NULL path accessing it results in a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

**Question 1: The template is `strdup()`ed and the result is non-NULL. How on earth can this result in an EXC_BAD_ACCESS?**

Now further down the rabbit hole. Let's get rid of the warnings. Checking `unistd.h` I find the declaration hidden by the pre processor.

```
#if     !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
...
char    *mkdtemp(char *);
...
#endif
```

Adding `-D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE` to the build makes all the problems go away but leaves me with a platform specific build. The 10.6 man page just says

```
 Standard C Library (libc, -lc)
 #include <unistd.h>
```

Removing the `_XOPEN_SOURCE` from the build makes is work on OSX but then it fails to compile under Linux with

```
warning: ‘struct FTW’ declared inside parameter list
warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
In function ‘tmp_remove’:
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘nftw’
error: ‘FTW_DEPTH’ undeclared (first use in this function)
error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
error: for each function it appears in.)
error: ‘FTW_PHYS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

**Question 2: So how would you fix this?**

The only fix I have found is to `#undef` _POSIX_C_SOURCE right before the `unistd.h` include ...but that feels like an ugly hack.

Comment: mkdtemp is not base POSIX -- according to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkstemp.html it's in the extended API. Segfault: are you sure u

Comment: you pass in a char * and not a const char *?

Comment: I know `mkdtemp` is not base POSIX. But it seems like `_XOPEN_SOURCE` causes `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to be defined. Still would like to use `mkdtemp` and the `ftw` API.

Comment: As for `const char*` see above. It's a literal copied via `strdup`. So that should be fine.

Comment: @H2CO3 er, CX there actually means it is in POSIX but not in ANSI C. The problem is that OSX doesn't apparently support the version of POSIX it was added in.

Comment: What happens if you add the "`char *mkdtemp(char *);`" declaration manually?

Comment: @Random832 I didn't test it - but given that a manual declaration is the same as using #undef I am quite confident it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked two questions here, and I'm just going to answer the first:

> Question 1: The template is strdup()ed and the result is non-NULL. How on earth can this result in an EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

As the warnings above tell you:

> warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mkdtemp’

This means it couldn't find the declaration for `mkdtemp`. By C rules, that's allowed, but it's assuming the function returns an int.

> warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

You've told the compiler "I've got a function that returns int, and I want to store the value in a char*". It's warning you that this is a bad idea. You can still do it, and therefore it compiles.

But think about what happens at runtime. The actual code you link to returns a 64-bit char*. Then your code treats that as a 32-bit int that it has to cast to a 64-bit char*. How likely is that to work?

This is why you don't ignore warnings.

Comment: Since the other question seems to have no easy answer I accept this one.

Answer (score 0):

And now for the second question:

> Question 2: So how would you fix this?

Your problem is that you're explicitly passing -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700, but you're using a function, mkdtemp, that isn't defined in the standard you're demanding. That means your code shouldn't work. The fact that it does work on linux doesn't mean your code is correct or portable, just that you happened to get lucky on one platform.

So, there are two rather obvious ways to fix this:

1. If you want to use _XOPEN_SOURCE=700, rewrite your code to only use functions that are in that standard.
2. If you've only added _XOPEN_SOURCE=700 as a hack that you don't really understand because it seemed to fix some other problem on linux, find the right way to fix that problem on linux.

It may turn out that there's a bug on one platform or another so there just is no right way to fix it. Or, more likely, you're using a combination of non-standard functions that can be squeezed in on different platforms with a different set of flags on each. In that case, your Makefile (or whatever drives the build) will have to pass different flags to the compiler on different platforms. This is pretty typical for cross-platform projects; just be glad you only have one flag to worry about, and aren't building 3000 lines worth of autoconf.

Comment: I only added `_XOPEN_SOURCE` because I want to use the `ftw` API. And apparently that also forces `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`. Is there an overview somewhere what is which standard?

Comment: Well, linux's manpage for http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/7/feature_test_macros/ has a lot of info… as do sections 1 and 2.2 of recent OpenGroup standards (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/contents.html). But everything in one place? Sadly, not that I know of. (And besides, both linux and OS X contain lots of extensions that may be in the next standard beyond the one they currently support, etc.) Meanwhile, FTW isn't new in XOpen 7—in fact, it was marked obsolete in XOpen 7—so I'm not sure that's the right way to bring it in.

Comment: First off - thanks for link! Very useful. `ftw` marked obsolete? *sigh* Open can - worms - everywhere. Initially I used the `fts` API but compiling on Linux I end up with `#error "<fts.h> cannot be used with -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS==64"`

Comment: IIRC, fts is a BSD extension that linux has copied but that still hasn't landed in POSIX, which means even if it worked, you'd probably end up with code that was "portable" to linux and *BSD (including OS X) but nowhere else, which is a great way to delude youself… The sad answer here is that there is no completely portable complete alternative. Which means you're going to have to do some portability hacking. Having a one-line platform check in the Makefile is much less painful than what most projects have to deal with…

Comment: Given that I only care about Linux and OS X at this stage - that's OK for now. Not using _FILE_OFFSET_BITS was an OK compromise that let me escape out of that "hell". Thanks for you input, guys.

Comment: `mkdtemp()` is part of POSIX 2008 and with `_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` you are requesting POSIX 2008 definitions. Perhaps Mac OS X doesn't implement POSIX 2008?